# Getting a hold on how to use jQuery Deferreds with my AJAX calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 2 sections in my webpage that require individual AJAX calls followed by the templating of data before injecting the content into the DOM. Right now I'm looking at the best way of doing this and I've been reading a lot of articles about jQuery Deferreds, so many to the point that I'm not entirely sure what the best way is. Below is the code that I think I would use but I would really appreciate some input. I'm also super hazy about caching if anyone would like to add some advice about that.

JS

```
function ajaxCall1() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/url1',
        data: { },
        success: function(data) {
            // Run templating code
        }
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}

function ajaxCall2() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/url2',
        data: { },
        success: function(response) {
            // Run templating code
        }
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}

$.when( ajaxCall1(), ajaxCall2() )
   .then(function(){
      // Display DOM elements
   })
   .fail(function(){
      // Display error message
   });
```

Comment: Have you tried that code? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

In order to work with Deferreds you should

```
1 - generate a new $.Deferred()
2 - return its .promise() from the function
3 - .resolve() the deferred in the callback of the Ajax request
```

Something in the lines of

```
function ajaxCall1() {
   var dfd = new $.Deferred();
   $.ajax({
      ...
      success: function(data) {
         dfd.resolve(data);
      }
   });
   return dfd.promise();
}

function ajaxCall2() {
   var dfd = new $.Deferred();
   $.ajax({
      ...
      success: function(data) {
         dfd.resolve(data);
      }
   });
   return dfd.promise();
}

$.when(ajaxCall1(), ajaxCall2()).then(function(data1, data2) {
   // data1 holds the result of the first ajax call, data2 that of the second call
});
```

EDIT: Since $.ajax() already returns a deferred, you could do it simply like

```
function ajaxCall1() {
   return $.ajax({
      ...
   });
}

function ajaxCall2() {
   return $.ajax({
      ...
   });
}

$.when(ajaxCall1(), ajaxCall2()).done(function(data1, data2) {
   // data1 holds the result of the first ajax call, data2 that of the second call
});
```

Comment: ah ok, so from inside the $.when i template data1 and data2 then do my injecting etc from there?

Comment: hey jack so what does that mean?

Comment: ah ok I see, so anything that isnt AJAX i would create a Deferred object then resolve it

Comment: yeah, you can do it both ways ... check first if the method doesn't already return an object that implements the deferred interface

Comment: and how could i add in caching as well as this is something I'm very unsure about?